# Add number range to select options

Tags: jquery, select

I have a `select` looking something like this:

```
<select id="address">
  <option noodd="1-9" noeven="2-6">Address Name 1</option>
  <option noodd="3-5" noeven="2-10">Address Name 2</option>
  <option noodd="3-11" noeven="1-5">Address Name 3</option>
</select>

<select id="housenumber">
</select>
```

Whenever one of the options in `#address` is selected, I need `#housenumber` to be filled with the numbers within the ranges of the address selected. So when `Address Name 1` is selected, I need `#housenumber` to look like this:

```
<select id="housenumber">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>9</option>
</select>
```

Does anyone have a clever idea how to do that?

**UPDATE**, what I need is this:

- A function that finds all equal numbers between the numbers specified in `noeven` for each `option`.
- A function that finds all odd numbers between the numbers specified in `noodd` for each `option`.
- A function that combines those two lists and puts them into `option` elements
- A function that appends these `option` elements to `#housenumber` whenever the corresponding `option` in `#address` is selected

Comment: what exactly are 'noodd' and 'noeven' used for?

Comment: Those are avaiable house numbers on the selected street. So it's the range of odd and even house numbers. I'm retrieving the data from JSON that I don't have access to change, so this is the only data I've got.

Comment: I just don't understand how you got your result html. Why isn't there an option with value 8?

Comment: Because the even range only ranges from 2 to 6 (`noeven="2-6"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
$('#address').change(function(){
    var $selected = $('option:selected',this);
    var odd = $selected.attr('noodd').split('-');
    var even = $selected.attr('noeven').split('-');

    var arr = [];
    for(var o = parseInt(odd[0],10);o<=parseInt(odd[1],10);o+=2){
       arr.push(o);  
    }

    for(var e = parseInt(even[0],10);e<=parseInt(even[1],10);e+=2){
       arr.push(e);  
    }

    var $housenumber = $('#housenumber');
    $housenumber.empty();
    $.each(arr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;}),function(i,e){
       $housenumber.append($('<option/>').text(e));
    });
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/uhwMS/

A couple of notes:

1. You should use `data-*` attributes rather than custom ones. Making your option nodes look like `<option data-odd="1-9" data-even="2-6">Address Name 1</option>` making reading them safer, eg `var odd = $selected.data('odd').split('-');`
2. Your third element has odd numbers for even, giving some strange results. Assume this was just ann error posting the question?

Comment: Thanks. I've also started playing around with push, and I'll try to combine what I've figured out with your code. 1. Thanks, I'll do that. 2. Yup, that was an error